# Es soll dein Schaden nicht sein (translate from story)

Tags: german-to-english

In Leserabe "Die Schatzinsel", the boy is describing the Captain, who says to the boy:

> Junge, wenn dir irgendwo ein einbeiniger Seemann begegnet, so lass es mich wissen! Es soll dein Schaden nicht sein.

My best translation is:

> Boy, when you encounter somewhere a one-legged sailor, let me know. It shouldn't be your fault.

The second sentence doesn't make sense.  There must be a more idiomatic translation.  Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Es soll dein Schaden nicht sein" = "I'll make it worth your while". Both are implicit promises of reward, e.g. in situations where such  deals wouldn't be strictly legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This an idiomatic phrase that works with the negation of *Schaden*:

- der Schaden (noun) = damage, harm, disadvantage

Lets look at a version of the phrase without *nicht*:

> Es soll dein Schaden sein.
>   It shall be your disadvantage.

But the phrase contains a negation. So it says:

> Es soll dein Schaden **nicht** sein.
>   It shall be your **non**-disadvantage.

So in fact you are talking about the opposite of a disadvantage, which is:

- der Nutzen = benefit, profit, advantage

So in fact the phrase means:

> Es soll dein Nutzen sein.
>   It shall be your advantage.

---

In a normal sentence the position of *nicht* in the phrase is a little bit strange. But in this special idiomatic phrase it is correct.

Comment: Thank you Hubert.  You can see I made two attempts to answer my own question.  Your explanation certainly fits with my re-reading of the original English. In the original, the Captain explicitly offers to pay Jim 4-pence per month for his efforts.

Comment: The rarely-used "shall" works well here.  "It shall be to your advantage."

Comment: While you correctly told the meaning of the *idiom*, your breakdown is wrong. The negation does not apply to "Schaden" but to "sein". So *literally* the sentence says "It shall not be to your disadvantage". Also note that negation and opposite are not the same.

Comment: celtschk is imho correct, therefor no upvote from me. "It shall be your non-disadvantage" would be a wrong translation, I would rather write the same as celtschk.

Comment: The literal meaning is indeed "It shall not be to your disadvantage", but I think it's an understatement, so the actual meaning is "You will be rewarded for it".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers, but i would like to add

> It will not be to your disadvantage

as found in The [Oxford-Duden German Dictionary: German-English, English-German](https://books.google.de/books?id=NTPKLFGB2FkC&pg=PA642&lpg=PA642&dq=%22It%20will%20not%20be%20to%20your%20disadvantage%22&source=bl&ots=FVR2daDE_C&sig=3C2J4A4iTky_Nn4jWNtxEnK889k&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit6N_q7OrfAhWFhywKHT2kBNIQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20will%20not%20be%20to%20your%20disadvantage%22&f=false) or [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Es+soll+dein+Schade+nicht+sein.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Hubert's answer:

> It should not be your loss.

Is also a valid translation for the expression. I am having a bit of troubles envisioning a seaman using the term "disadvantage". But then again there is enough time to read a dictionary on a journey. Especially when you end up stranded.

Answer (score -3):

The source of the confusion is the translation of "Shaden".

My new best-guess is that this whole phrase would translate into:

"It should not be any concern to you."
more poetically:
"But don't let that be a burden to you." or "But think no more about it."

Perhaps someone can comment on why the English phrasings want a strong contradiction (i.e. start the sentence with "but"/"however"), but the German uses "Es" rather than "Aber"/"Trotzdem".

Comment: I no longer think this is the right translation.  See my other answer (with reading of the original)

Comment: See Hubert's answer for a correct translation.  I leave my earlier attempt here because sometimes seeing the mistakes of others can be informative.

Comment: If you think your answer is wrong, better delete it. Others may read only the answer and may oversee your comment.

Answer (score -3):

This sentence: "Es soll dein Shaden nicht sein."  Has been haunting me :)
Since this came for a children's version and a translation, I first went back to the adult version (in German), and tried to find the intended meaning in the story that lead to this sentence.
I then went back to the original English, and I now have a new theory: In the original story, the Captain IS very concerned about the one-legged man.  He even pays the boy (Jim) to keep his eye out for the one-legged man.

So the best meaning seems to be:
"It would be a shame for you if you didn't (inform me)."
To close the par between the desired meaning (above) and the German sentence for the children's book, I'll make it this:

```
"It should, for you, be a shame     (if) not (you inform me)."
"Es soll    dein     [sein] Shaden      nicht                  sein."
```

I would appreciate any comments which can help clarify how "nicht" can do so much work: It seems to encompass both the conditional idea of "if/when", and at least one extra verb (either "you do" or "you (not) inform me".

(Final thought: perhaps it's the "soll" that accomplishes the constitutionality which I seem to be seeking.)

Comment: See Hubert's answer for a correct translation.  I leave my earlier attempt here because sometimes seeing the mistakes of others can be informative.